# Функция prompt не дает обновлять значение

Tags: javascript, html

[image: изображение1]

На изображении представлена фраза и снизу должны появляться буквы после каждого ввода в диалоговое окно prompt. Но почему-то этого не происходит, после prompt нажимаешь OK и не добавляет, запускает следующий prompt и так до конца. И только после последнего успешного prompt появляется фраза полностью.

```js
let words = [
  "программа",
  "макака",
  "прекрасный",
  "оладушек"
];

let word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
let par = document.getElementById("word");
let wordSave = [];

for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  wordSave[i] = "_";
  par.innerHTML = wordSave.join(" ");
}

window.onload = function() {
  let a = 0;
  let shot = 5;
  while (shot > 0) {
    let letter = prompt("Угадай букву!" + "Осталось " + shot + " попыток");

    if (letter == null) break;

    if (letter.length == 1) {
      let count = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (letter === word[i]) {
          if (wordSave.indexOf(word[i]) == -1) alert("Угадал букву!");
          wordSave[i] = word[i];
          console.log(wordSave);
          par.innerHTML = wordSave.join(" ");

          if (wordSave.indexOf(word[i]) == -1) alert("Угадал букву!");
        } else count++;
      }
      if (wordSave.indexOf("_") === -1) {
        alert("Слово угадано");
        break;
      }
      if (count === word.length) {
        alert("Нет такой буквы");
        shot--;
      }
      a++
    } else {
      alert("Ошибка. Попробуйте еще раз");
    }
  }
}
console.log(word);
```

```html
<h1>Угадайте слово</h1>
<p id="word"></p>
```

Кстати на IE должным образом работает, а в Chrome не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Так и должно быть. Циклы выполняются за один кадр. То есть вы не даёте случиться отрисовке кадра. Для этого нужна какая-то асинхронная задача, а ваш код весь синхронный. Например вместо while после каждого ответа на вопрос сделайте setTimeout, который вызывает прежнюю функцию через 0 секунд. Тогда синхронность разорвётся и у браузера появится шанс отрисовать кадр.